# Nested Hashmaps overwriting other keys

Tags: java, hashmap, nested

I have a problem where when I want to change a value in a nested HashMap, the other HashMaps are being overwritten.

for example I have a key name Alligator, which stores a HashMap that contains the keys Weight and Size. I want to be able to change the value associated with Size, but not affect Weight at all. In a yml file, this is what it would look like.

```
Alligator:
  Weight: 100.0
  Size: 10.0
```

And this is what I would like to happen.

```
Alligator:
  Weight: 150.0
  Size: 10.0
```

This was Some Code that I found earlier that lets me change the values, but with overwriting...

```
HashMap< String, HashMap< String, Double>> data = new HashMap<>();

       data.put("Alligator", new HashMap() {
            {
                put("Size", 10.0
            }
        });

HashMap< String, HashMap< String, Double>> data = new HashMap<>();

       data.put("Alligator", new HashMap() {
            {
                put("Weight", 100.0
            }
        });
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile

Comment: I would suggest to create a class `Alligator` with two fields `size` and `weight`.

Comment: the code was a snippet from my program with some parts reworded. Luckily my question was answered fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A

```
new HashMap(){ // blablabla
```

means a new Object instance in the memery,

and a

```
data.put("Alligator", new HashMap() { // blablabla
```

means adding(key not exists) or overwriting(key exists) a KV pair in the data map.

As @Eran suggests,

```
inner = data.get("Alligator")
```

checking if *inner* exists

Comment: Thanks! This was easy for me to understand and helped me fix the problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
   data.put("Alligator", new HashMap() {
        {
            put("Weight", 100.0);
        }
    });
```

would overwrite the internal Map of the "Alligator" key if it's already in the outer Map.

You must check for existence first :

```
Map<String, Double> inner = data.get("Alligator");
if (inner != null) {
    inner.put("Weight", 100.0);
} else {
    data.put ("Alligator", new HashMap() {
        {
            put("Weight", 100.0);
        }
    });
}
```

BTW, I wouldn't use an anonymous sub-class of `HashMap` instance for the inner Map.
You can replace it with this simpler code :

```
Map<String, Double> inner = data.get("Alligator");
if (inner == null) {
    inner = new HashMap<>();     
    data.put ("Alligator",inner);
}
inner.put("Weight", 100.0);
```

Comment: The last code block wont actually put the new HashMap you created for "Alligator" into the outer "data" HashMap.

Comment: @DTing Oops. Thanks for catching my omission. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First handle what you want to happen if there is no "Alligator" in your data `HashMap`, possibly put in a new `HashMap` for "Alligator":

```
if (!data.containsKey("Alligator")) {
  data.put("Alligator", new HashMap<>());
}
```

Then use `get` to grab the nested HashMap and use `put` to change the values:

```
HashMap<String, Double> alligator = data.get("Alligator");
alligator.put("Weight", 150.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Crate a inner HashMap with different name, so you never get confused between two maps.

```
Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> outermap = new HashMap<String,Map<String,Integer>>();
        Map<String,Integer> innermap1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();


        innermap1.put("Weight",100);
        innermap1.put("Size", 10);
        outermap.put("Alligator",innermap1);
```